# How to get the ID of each node from topological sort?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a network (a directed acyclic graph):

```
dag_1 <- barabasi.game(20)
```

I applied a topological sort:

```
top1 <- topo_sort(dag_1)
top1
+ 20/20 vertices, from 0ee5d26:
 [1]  5  8 11 13 14 15 16 17 18 20  4  7 12 19  2 10  9  6  3  1
```

If I type `top1` and hit enter, the results are above. I need to access the vector

`5 8 11 13, ..., 1`

I tried `top1[1]` and `top1[[1]]`. Neither of them gave me the vector.

How can I get it?

Comment: `as.vector(top1)` will return the vector

Comment: Hi @Djork, if you write that as an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: Sure thing! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`top1` is an `igraph.vs` class object, and indexing e.g. `top1[1:10]` returns the vertices of the graph. To return a vector of the vertices use:

```
as.vector(top1)
```